# Swift texfield input: pickerView, throws constraint error

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, nslayoutconstraint

When I click on of the five textfield, the picker view comes up but this error comes up. when you click on the lower two textfields the picker view doesn't´t come up. If  I make this whole thing inside a scroll view the lower textfields work also with the picker view. I couldn't´t find anything how to fix this qwq all the stuff in the view controller ist autoresized.

image of the storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeFwu.jpg

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Charts
import CoreData

class ExamViewController: TabView, ChartViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var block1Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var block2Label: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var P1Field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var P1Points: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var P2Field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var P2Points: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var P3Field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var P3Points: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var P4Field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var P4Points: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var P5Field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var P5Points: UITextField!
    

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    
    var strCurrentFieldEditing: String = ""
    var picks: [String] = []
    var numberPicks: [String] = [ "0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]
    let subjectPicker = UIPickerView()
    let numberPicker = UIPickerView()
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    
    let notificationAlert = UIAlertController(title: "qwq", message: "qwq#2", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        update()
        
        subjectPicker.delegate = self
        numberPicker.delegate = self
        
        P1Field.delegate = self
        P2Field.delegate = self
        P3Field.delegate = self
        P4Field.delegate = self
        P5Field.delegate = self
        
        P1Field.inputView = subjectPicker
        P1Field.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        P2Field.inputView = subjectPicker
        P2Field.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        P3Field.inputView = subjectPicker
        P3Field.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        P4Field.inputView = subjectPicker
        P4Field.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        P5Field.inputView = subjectPicker
        P5Field.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        self.navigationItem.title = "Prüfungsübersicht"
        
        notificationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(
            width: scrollView.visibleSize.width,
            height: scrollView.visibleSize.height*1.1
        )
    }
    
    func pickUp(_ textField : UITextField){
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.accentColor
       toolBar.sizeToFit()
       
        
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ExamViewController.donePicker))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ExamViewController.cancelPicker))
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     }
    
    @objc func donePicker() {
        if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P1"){
            P1Field.resignFirstResponder()
        }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P2"){
            P2Field.resignFirstResponder()
        }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P3"){
            P3Field.resignFirstResponder()
        }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P4"){
            P4Field.resignFirstResponder()
        }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P5"){
            P5Field.resignFirstResponder()
        }
       update()
    }
    
    @objc func cancelPicker(){
        if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P1"){
            P1Field.resignFirstResponder()
            P1Points.text = nil
        }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P2"){
            P2Field.resignFirstResponder()
            P2Points.text = nil
        }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P3"){
            P3Field.resignFirstResponder()
            P3Points.text = nil
        }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P4"){
            P4Field.resignFirstResponder()
            P4Points.text = nil
        }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P5"){
            P5Field.resignFirstResponder()
            P5Points.text = nil
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
        update()
    }
    
    
    // MARK: UIPickerView Delegation
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if(component == 0){
            return picks.count
        }else {
            return numberPicks.count
        }
    }
    
    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if(component == 0){
            return  picks[row]
        }else {
            return  numberPicks[row]
        }
    }
    
    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if(picks.count == 0) {
            self.present(self.notificationAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return }
        if(component == 0){
            if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P1"){
                P1Field.text = picks[row]
            }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P2"){
                P2Field.text = picks[row]
            }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P3"){
                P3Field.text = picks[row]
            }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P4"){
                P4Field.text = picks[row]
            }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P5"){
                P5Field.text = picks[row]
            }
        }else {
            if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P1"){
                P1Points.text = numberPicks[row]
            }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P2"){
                P2Points.text = numberPicks[row]
            }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P3"){
                P3Points.text = numberPicks[row]
            }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P4"){
                P4Points.text = numberPicks[row]
            }else if(strCurrentFieldEditing == "P5"){
                P5Points.text = numberPicks[row]
            }
        }
    }
    

    
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if(picks.count == 0){ return false}
        if(textField == P1Field){
            self.strCurrentFieldEditing = "P1"
        }else if(textField == P2Field){
            self.strCurrentFieldEditing = "P2"
        }else if(textField == P3Field){
            self.strCurrentFieldEditing = "P3"
        }else if(textField == P4Field){
            self.strCurrentFieldEditing = "P4"
        }else if(textField == P5Field){
            self.strCurrentFieldEditing = "P5"
        }
        self.pickUp(textField)
        return true
    }
    
    
    func update() {
        picks = Util.getAllSubjectNames()
        if((picks.firstIndex(of: P1Field.text ?? "")) != nil){
            picks.remove(at: picks.firstIndex(of: P1Field.text ?? "")!)
        }
        if((picks.firstIndex(of: P2Field.text ?? "")) != nil){
            picks.remove(at: picks.firstIndex(of: P2Field.text ?? "")!)
        }
        if((picks.firstIndex(of: P3Field.text ?? "")) != nil){
            picks.remove(at: picks.firstIndex(of: P3Field.text ?? "")!)
        }
        if((picks.firstIndex(of: P4Field.text ?? "")) != nil){
            picks.remove(at: picks.firstIndex(of: P4Field.text ?? "")!)
        }
        if((picks.firstIndex(of: P5Field.text ?? "")) != nil){
            picks.remove(at: picks.firstIndex(of: P5Field.text ?? "")!)
        }
       
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

So this my error

````
2021-10-29 15:16:32.284195+0200 Calq[3986:101986] Writing analzed variants.
objc[3986]: Class _PathPoint is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x118606a78) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x136e958b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3986]: Class _PointQueue is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x118606a50) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x136e958d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2021-10-29 15:16:32.594144+0200 Calq[3986:101986] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f0960 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8620b429e0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012e0730 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8620b43290]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8620b429e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012e0780 H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8620b43290]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8620b429e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012fb6b0 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f861ff7c3b0'Cancel']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7be90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012fb700 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f861ff7c3b0'Cancel']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7be90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f0000 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000008a3020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7be90.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f0230 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000008a3020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7eb70.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f0280 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7be90]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f861ff7ea00]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f02d0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f861ff7ea00]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7eb70]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012e0550 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000008a3020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8620b43290 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012e05f0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000008a3020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8620b43290 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012fb700 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f861ff7c3b0'Cancel']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7be90 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-10-29 15:16:32.595554+0200 Calq[3986:101986] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f0960 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8620b429e0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012e0730 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8620b43290]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8620b429e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012e0780 H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8620b43290]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8620b429e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012fbca0 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f861ff7ed50'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7eb70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012fbcf0 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f861ff7ed50'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7eb70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f0000 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000008a3020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7be90.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f0230 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000008a3020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7eb70.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f0280 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7be90]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f861ff7ea00]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012f02d0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f861ff7ea00]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7eb70]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012e0550 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000008a3020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8620b43290 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012e05f0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000008a3020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8620b43290 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000012fbcf0 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f861ff7ed50'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f861ff7eb70 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.```
````

Comment: Constrains of your views are incorrect, Check every view constraint & fix it. Constrain overlapping occurring in your storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

The auto layout warnings are related to "internal" UIKit elements.

You can avoid those warning by replacing this line:

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
```

with this:

```
let toolBar: UIToolbar = {
    let v = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 44.0)))
    return v
}()
```

That will initialize the toolbar with a width of `200` ... it doesn't need to be specifically 200, it just needs to be wide enough to fit the width of your `UIBarButtonItem` buttons.